# Cómo se traduce apropiadamente "Bump a thread"?

Tags: traducción, jerga-internet

Cuando se habla de "Bump" en el contexto de foros, por ejemplo, se asocia al hecho de hacer que una conversación pase a estar como recientemente modificada, y por ende, primera en el listado.

¿Qué traducción sería la más apropiada en ese contexto?

Comment: "Reflotar" es una metáfora bastante entendible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yo usaría

> Revivir el tema o la discusión

Comment: La había pensado, pero supuse que no se entendería. Siendo la respuesta más votada, tengo que concluir que sí se entendería si lo traduzco así :) Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Opciones que considero posibles en este contexto pero que no me convencen mucho:

- Sacudir conversación
- Agitar conversación
- Golpear conversación
- Resaltar conversación (esta ya creo que pierde el significado real)